# Javascript upload file via web console

Tags: javascript, html

anyone please help me ,normally i can upload file by : click upload button ->choose file to upload->click OK, but now i want to upload a file use 'javascript' via web console ,example the file : `c:/data.pdf` .And
this is file input tag `<a id="btnBrowse" href="javascript:void(0);" related_btn_id="ansyc_js_solution_file_1" is_inited="true">
<span class="icon icon-attachment-add"></span>
Attach files
</a>
<span class="remark"> ( File Format: Jpeg, Jpg, Gif, Png, PDF, PPT, Word or Excel Maximum File Size: 3MB ) </span>` .

`<input id="file_ipt_id" class="superbig" type="file" onchange="upload()" size="1" name="file">`
Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can't select a file without the "open file" dialog being shown.

Comment: why so ,you already know the path :c:/data.pdf ,i think we always have a solution ,but i and you dont know ..

Comment: If this was possible, any website could download files from your computer by making guesses from a list of paths.

Comment: How about the answer below ,sabof ??? ,i dont know how to change to my situation

Comment: Nup. Systems paths are off limits to any script.